# Simple Android Wifi Connection

Tags: android, android-wifi

My code was returning Null Bss. Anyone knows how to implement it to work? Just want to connect to an Wifi NetWork from my home.
Thanks.

```
public class Scan extends AppCompatActivity {

public String ssid;
public String password;
public String security;


public EditText nome, senha, tipo;
public Button connectar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSSID);
    senha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPASS);
    tipo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTIPO);




}



public void connectar(View view){
    //Toast.makeText(Scan.this, "Conectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String ssidC = nome.getText().toString();
    String senhaC = senha.getText().toString();
    String tipoC = tipo.getText().toString();

    connect(ssidC, senhaC, tipoC);
}



public void connect(String ssid, String password, String security){

    WifiConfiguration wfc = new WifiConfiguration();

    wfc.SSID = "\"".concat(ssid).concat("\"");
    wfc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.DISABLED;
    wfc.priority = 40;


    if(security.equals("WPA2")){
        wfc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        wfc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
        wfc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
        wfc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        wfc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
        wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
        wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
        wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
        wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);

        wfc.preSharedKey = "\"".concat(password).concat("\"");

    }

    WifiManager wfMgr = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    int networkId = wfMgr.addNetwork(wfc);
    if (networkId != -1) {
        wfMgr.enableNetwork(networkId, true);
    }

}

}
```

I am passing the SSID, PASSWORD and WPA2 on my EditText.
The logcat was saying BSS was null.

Comment: wpa_supplicant_select_bss: selected_bss is null